# How to call main() method of a class using reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

When calling the main method of a Java class from another main method using reflection,

```
Class thisClass = loader.loadClass(packClassName);
Method thisMethod = thisClass.getDeclaredMethod("main",String[].class);

thisMethod.invoke(null, new String[0]);
```

Should i create newInstance() or simply call main() as it is static.

Comment: Is there a constructor takes the parameter type String[]?

Comment: Is the `main` method static? If so, why are you creating an instance of the class? If not, then the call to `invoke` is wrong.

Comment: actually, when i call non-parameterized method it work correctly, but it does not work properly in parameterized method... why so ?

Comment: @RedSoxFan yah... i want to call main method and its having parameter as String... s or String[] s

Comment: now i get,
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your stated requirements (dynamically invoke the main method of a random class, with reflection you have alot of unnecessary code.

- You do not need to invoke a constructor for the class
- You do not need to introspect the classes fields
- Since you are invoking a static method, you do not even need a real object to invoke the method on

You can adapt the following code to meet your needs:

```
try {
    final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("blue.RandomClass");
    final Method method = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);

    final Object[] args = new Object[1];
    args[0] = new String[] { "1", "2"};
    method.invoke(null, args);
} catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perceptions answer looks correct; if you need load from a Jar not in the class path you can use a URL class loader

```
     try {
        URL[] urls;
        URLClassLoader urlLoader;

        urls = ...;

        urlLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class runClass = urlLoader.loadClass(classToRun);

        Object[] arguments = new Object[]{args};
        Method mainMethod = runClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        mainMethod.invoke(null, arguments);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```